# editing buttons (hyperlinks) disappear (on Firefox)

Tags: bug

Since about two days ago (perhaps Feb. 20 or 21 2018), the editing buttons (hyperlinks) disappear. Here is a small screenshot about editing my [Measure static, heap and stack memory ? (c++, Linux - Centos 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910614/measure-static-heap-and-stack-memory-c-linux-centos-7/48947559#48947559) answer

[image: partial screenshot of my Firefox browser editing an answer]

As you see, there is no buttons like "bold", "italics", "hyperlink", "quotes". Actually I do happen to see these buttons for a fraction of a second (perhaps 0.5 to 1 second; I have time to see them, but not to use them), but then they vanish (and passing the mouse on the "empty" zone containing them don't change anything)

This only happens on firefox 52.6.0, my preferred browser (on Linux/Debian/Sid/unstable). I am able to edit questions on Google Chrome.
I am using the Grammarly for Firefox addon (version 8.817.1473) which shows the red bar and I really need it, because I am not a native English speaker.

For me, it is an annoying bug (BTW it happens both at work and at home, with slightly different Firefox versions) I really prefer to use Firefox.
I'm located in France, and usually browse between 7:00am and 21:00pm CET time

BTW, upgrading the browser to Firefox 58.0.1 don't solve the problem. JavaScript don't seems to be disabled (e.g. the URL `javascript:alert("hello")` works, and demos like https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ are working)

Here is my browser's settings: https://whatismybrowser.com/w/QT5YQ6G

Complex websites like http://www.bbc.com/ or http://quora.com/ look good in my browser.

When using private browsing mode, the problem is still here.

On another laptop with Ubuntu 17 & Firefox 58.0.2 with a fresh account, I don't have that issue.

---

This bug is apparently fixed on February 28<sup>th</sup> 2018 (even with Firefox 52.6)

Comment: Tricky situation.  52.6.0 ESR is still officially supported but it's not within "the last two" of Firefox's latest release, which would not satisfy [Stack's own browser support requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).

Comment: I just upgraded to 58.0.1 (`aptitude install firefox; aptitude purge firefox-esr`) and that don't solve the issue.

Comment: Got any plugins or anything around that might be blocking JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Try viewing the page in private browsing mode (this will disable all plugins / extensions / userscripts / settings / etc.).

Comment: @TinyGiant: That (private browsing mode) is a workaround (and then, I prefer another one: use Chrome to edit posts). I really think there is some *recent* bug on StackOverflow's side. I'm willing to provide more information if that helps.

Comment: No, private browsing mode is just a debugging step. If using private browsing mode fixes the issue that means that it was a plugin / extension / userscript / setting or combination thereof causing the problem. If not, then it is a problem outside of that scope. We can guess till the cows come home, or we can test it.

Comment: @TinyGiant: the problem is still here. BTW, I won't use my computer this weekend.

Comment: If the problem still exists while using private browsing mode, that means it is either a problem in the browser itself or SO. The next step would be to open the browser console and check for any errors logged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow editor tools menu hidden when grammarly addon enabled on Firefox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363954/stack-overflow-editor-tools-menu-hidden-when-grammarly-addon-enabled-on-firefox)