# Editor toolbar layout broken in IE 10

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, editor, internet-explorer

This happened in maybe the last week or so and the toolbar is now vertical which makes it really annoying to use. I'm stuck with IE 10 so hopefully whatever CSS changes that have been made can be reverted or worked around.

[image: IE 10 editor toolbar]

Possibly related to 
[editing buttons (hyperlinks) disappear (on Firefox)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363762/editing-buttons-hyperlinks-disappear-on-firefox).

**Edit:**

And things just got worse (May 17ish 2017), it is now a horizontal toolbar but all the buttons except the first one is invisible! With the previous issue it was at least usable but now I have no buttons and making this post is a struggle in itself!

[image: One button toolbar]

The fix posted by Decoy still works correctly, please add it to your code in delay loaded javascript for old browsers or something like that.

Comment: **"Stuck with IE10"**. Sounds like the name of a comedy-horror movie. Still, not as scary as the original: **"Stuck with IE7"**.

Comment: @Yivi that comedy-horror movie would be sure to keep you on the **Edge** of your seat... Okay that sounded funnier in my head.

Comment: Have you tried with Microsoft Internet Explhorror ?

Comment: So this is what a responsive website would look like on a Windows Phone?

Comment: I think the toolbar and buttons are UL/LI tags so it makes sense for their "default" to be a list like this but I don't understand why they can't just be normal inline elements with wrapping done by the browser (if required). That should make it responsive without any CSS tricks.

Comment: I am guessing here, since I cba to fire up a VM and check, that the problem is flexbox and no `-ms` prefix. IE10 does not fully support flex layouts and a prefix is needed in some cases. If that is the case then it shouldn't be too difficult to fix, an autoprefixer should do it, if SO has any kind of build-step for their CSS.

Comment: Still in guessing mode, I would assume they prefer flexbox over linline layouts because it's a lot easier to work with. The tech kinda moved on and IE10 was left behind, IE11 has much better support, and last I checked even IE9 had more usage than IE10 does.

Comment: Run. **Run for your life.**

Comment: Do Stack Overflow has a published browser support policy? I can't find one, but if this was my site I'd be closing as won't fix. It doesn't work in Netscape 4 either.

Comment: @thelem there is one on MSE: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). Quotes: "we support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use" and "Internet Explorer (current version status from Wikipedia), exception: Internet Explorer on Mac OS X"

Comment: Suprisingly *not* repro'd on IE11

Comment: @CalvT븃 IE 10 also had a top bar bug when the new top bar came out that IE 11 did not have IIRC. It was fixed with a javascript workaround  after the page loads AFAIK.

Comment: It's worth noting that IE10 is ONLY supported on versions of Server 2012 IIRC. Given that's not a consumer operating system I would say it's safe to say that SE shouldn't be spending time supporting it.

Comment: @Mgetz With the ongoing deprecation of TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1+ only being supported by IE11 and higher by default, even having https with <=IE10 is going to be difficult soon

Comment: @JoshJanusch if a client asks me to support IE < 11 I require a signed Microsoft support contract with migration plan. We discourage IE11 too.

Comment: @Mgetz We're actually disabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 from all of our servers in the next month, regardless of client wishes. It's gotten to a point where we can't support it and also keep supporting the various third party services we use and their requirements

Comment: IE10 is still supported by SE. They support the last two versions of every major browser, and IE is in the list of major browsers.

Comment: @gparyani That doesn't necessarily mean anything, given IE has been abandoned in favor of Edge. That's like saying we indefinitely support IE10 because there will *never* be a version 12+. Not gonna happen. Generally if it's an easy fix someone will make it. Otherwise it's safe to say IE10 is unsupported.

Comment: @animuson [I thought so too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307455/should-we-stop-supporting-internet-explorer-10)

Comment: _Exploder_ rather sounds like a 1980s action movie. The plot will be something like: a greedy multinational company releases a software, secretly included in all computers delivered. This software grows sentient, then causes computers to explode everywhere around the world. There's no (net)scape, the apocalypse is here: it looks like Sky.NET will soon control everything. But some hero, played by Arnold, or perhaps Michael J Firefox, is sent from the future to save the world.

Comment: @Anders IE10 is not supported, as you may have seen from the comments already. It also reached official EOL over 2 years ago. What part of your environment causes you to be stuck with IE10? Windows 7, (which you must at least be on if you are using IE10) and newer all support IE11.

Comment: If graceful degradation is no longer a thing, are we also going to start deleting all [tag:css], etc. questions on the main site dealing with old/unsupported browsers/features, seeing how anyone who is using those browsers can no longer use the site?

Comment: @Jo.: What? Developers writing for old browsers don't all browse SO exclusively using those old browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the IE10 console:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.wmd-button-row li'),
  function(li) {
    li.style.float = 'left';
  }
);
```

Essentially it is selecting the list of controls and giving each one a "float: left".

The result looks like this:
[image: Editor in IE10]

*Edit* Note this is merely a workaround.

Comment: Why exactly are you using slice? Just doing `Array.from (document.querySelectorAll ())` will work as well, won't it?

Comment: @NikxDa Internet Explorer doesn't support `Array.from`, but it is correct to say that slice is not needed. `Array.prototype.forEach.call(NodeList, callback);` works fine.

Comment: Yes, your code fixes it for me as well.