# Stack Overflow editor tools menu hidden when grammarly addon enabled on Firefox

Tags: support, editor

I'm using [Grammarly](https://grammarly.com/) addon to Firefox browser for grammatical mistakes, I'm using this addon for almost all browsers on my computer, mostly used browsers are Chrome & Firefox, but when I write answer or question using Firefox with enabling Grammarly addon then Stack Overflow editor tools/menu hiding automatically, look at the below images.

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome that is working properly:

[image]

When I disable the addon from Firefox then it's working properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the reviews](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grammarly-1/reviews/) the add-on misbehaves on several websites, including Facebook and GitHub.

Report your problem to the developers of the add-on.