# The content on the right sidebar of the new "Ask a Question" page sometimes blinks and vanishes

Tags: support, bug, sidebar, ask-question-form

When typing in the "Question Body" of the new "Ask a Question" page, the content on the right sidebar sometimes blinks and/or vanishes.

Left: expected | Right: actual

[image: expected right sidebar] [image: vanishing right sidebar]

Is it a bug? If it matters, this is on Chrome 77, Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly *not* a bug on SE-side.

If you're using browser extensions, check and disable all of them, and enable one-by-one to find the cause.

---

For this case, it is caused by **Grammarly**, a browser extension that has caused display bugs on SE before (e.g. [editor toolbar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363954), [editing chat message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309926)). The content on the right sidebar will vanish when Grammarly checks your writing (showing rotating icon) and will reappear when it finishes checking (showing Grammarly icon or the number of mistakes).

Disabling it on Stack Overflow will fix the issue.

Note: Meta Stack Overflow and the rest of the sites with old "Ask a Question" page is not affected.